# Make infinite vertical lines with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

i trying to make train rails,
there is option to make infinite vertical lines without duplicate the rail_line div infinite times?

this is my code that i tried:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#rails .lines {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

#rails .lines .line {
  background: #000000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

#rails .rail {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 40px;
  height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rails .rail .rail_line {
  width: 1px;
  background: #000000;
  transform: rotate(17deg);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  top: -2px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="rails">
  <div class="lines">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rail">
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
    <div class="rail_line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lines">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can duplicate it with PHP \ JS but i want CSS option without create a lot of DOM elements
i put 8 lines for example but i want it responsive for each page width
TNX

Comment: You may use a gradient maybe but you'll always be limited to the width you set for `div.rail` or the default width the browser calculates for it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test {
  height: 70px;
    background-image: 
        repeating-linear-gradient(
            -80deg,
            transparent 0px,
             /* 0.5 transparent-black blur, optional */
            black 0.5px,
             /* 1px black line (total ~=1.5) */
            black 1.5px,
             /* 0.5 black-transparent blur, optional */
            transparent 2px,
            transparent 50px
        );
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```